# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

After updated my Wordpress Blog to PHP 7.2 I start getting the following error

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in on line 10

This is the line:

`add_action('gdlr_save_' + THEME_SLUG, 'gdlr_generate_style_custom');`

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Contact the creator of the plugin and ask him to fix the bug!

Comment: Replace + with .

Comment: as @CodyKL said, `+` is not used for concatenation in PHP, it's used for addition. That's why the interpreter is expecting a numeric value.

Comment: Replacing + with **.** the problem was solved. Thanks a lot!!!